# nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect() always returns 0 in Angular tests

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I have an Angular Component (5.2) that positions itself relative to the `nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()` output of another element.

In test, I have created a wrapper component with styles to simulate positioned elements, but the returned `ClientRect` is always all zeros.

Is there a way to ask Angular to *actually* position my element in a DOM?

For an illustration, here's my `TestComponent`. Internally the `<popup>` component will calculate it's fixed position using `anchor.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()`.

I don't think it's relevant, but I'm using Jest to execute the tests.

I've tried *with* and *without* `async()`.

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    styles: [`
        :host {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: center;
        }
    `],
    template: `
        <button #button></button>
        <popup [anchor]="button">
            <div id="helloWorld">hello world</div>
        </popup>
    `
})
class TestComponent {
    @ViewChild('button')
    public buttonElement: ElementRef;
}

describe('test', () => {
    let fixture;
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestComponent],
            imports: [PopupModule]
        }).compileComponents().then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });
    }));
    it('should be positioned', () => {
        const button = fixture.componentInstance.buttonElement.nativeElement;

        // Either of these always fail, because the button is not positioned.
        // I have also tried using fixed positioning of the button.

        // this will fail
        expect(button.getBoundingClientRect().top).not.toEqual(0);

        // this will fail, too
        return fixture.whenRenderingDone().then(() => {
            expect(button.getBoundingClientRect().top).not.toEqual(0);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I suppose this is a timing problem. Try to create the component in `beforeEach` and surround with `async`.

Comment: I've updated the example to illustrate usage of `async()`

Comment: Does `buttonElement.nativeElement` exist? If so, you could try accessing `button.offsetHeight` (just accessing it, no need to do anything with the value) to see if it forces the button to be positioned in the page.

Comment: @JeffFairley have you resolved this issue? I have it too

Comment: No. I believe it's a JSDOM issue. Probably intentional, because IDK what cost comes with calculating DOM sizes.

Answer (score 1):

*Long story short:*

You need to use `nativeElement` of `ElementRef` type only in ngAfterViewInit() hook, and your test will "see" the element in DOM.

*Long read:*

The `.getBoundingClientRect()` will work only if the element had rendered and exist in DOM. Today I faced the case when I tried to access the element which was clicked and with `[routerLink]` it was dynamically re-rendered by router action - I can't visually recognize this behavior. It causes this element disappears, and can't have any measurements. Next, some similar element was rendered but 0,0,0,0 in ClientRect.

So if you use some dynamic re-rendering of elements - like menus or some else, your `element.getBoundingClientRect()` will return 0,0,0,0 only if the element was disappeared, re-rendered, or at "action time" (click, etc) is not present in DOM yet as in your case.

So you need to wait while it will be re-rendered and next - you could get its measurements by `.getBoundingClientRect()`. For `@ViewChild()` best way to wait is `ngAfterViewInit()` hook, you can access to nativeElement in it (as a best way). Also - there are some tricks like:

```
private elementInited$ = new Subject();
public desiredElement: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('someElemRef') set setElementRef(el: ElementRef) {
  if (!!el) {
    this.desiredElement= el;
    this.elementInited$.next();
  }
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.elementInited$.subscribe((inited) => {
  // do stuff with nativeElement
  const values = this.desiredElement.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect() // <== works!
  })
}
```

But its too tricky :)

Also, a good way to wait on the element is a `@Directive()`.
With a directive, you can listen for an element properly, in "angular way", and directive will fire only if the element exist in DOM.

Also might very helpful to use Chrome's rendering highlights in Devtools - just open devtools menu - `More tools > rendering > Paint flashing` checkbox helps to recognize which of elements rerender.

Answer (score 0):

For me everything started to work only, when i used this method on my viewChild, element, which one i declared like this:

```
@ViewChild('progress', { static: true }) progress;
```

After that in could use `getBoundingClientRect` method.

```
this.progress.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
```

PS: It didn't worked for me, when i used ElementRef. Only with ViewChild it was ok.